# while uploading image to firebase, this one error is always comes whatever i do

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[image]

what went wrong? even if i replace the XFile into File, same error comes at this putFile.

Comment: what exactly is the error message ?

Comment: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Object>'.

Comment: 2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found.

Answer (score 0):

try this convert that xfile to file

```
uploadImages(XFile? pathsw) async {
    final paths = path.basename(pathsw!.path);
    final pathStorage =
        "${NAMEFOLDER}/${PATHNAME}/$paths";
   /// Start looking from here then so on
    final file = File(pathsw.path);
    final reference = FirestoreService.storage.ref().child(pathStorage);
    final task = reference.putFile(file);
    final snap = await task.whenComplete(() {});
    final url = await snap.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return url;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see, `.putFile()` takes in a element of `File` type. And you're accepting of type `XFile`.  To convert:

```
File uploadImage = File(image!.path)
```

now the best way to upload would be to use `.putFile()` or `.putData()`

Your `.putFile()` implementation looks great, if you want to use `.putData()`, find the following code:

```
await reference.putData(uploadImage.readAsBytesSync())
```